# How to structure Github APIv4 Golang Query for specific release

Tags: go, graphql, github-api

Using https://github.com/shurcooL/githubv4 and I'm really struggling to pull back a specific Release for a gh repo.

The below code block keeps returning nothing when there is a v3 release:

```
var releaseQ struct {
  Repository struct {
    Release struct {
        Author githubv4.String
    } `graphql:"release(tagName:$tagName)"`
  } `graphql:"repository(owner:$repositoryOwner,name:$repositoryName)"`
}
variables = map[string]interface{}{
    "repositoryOwner": githubv4.String("jacobtomlinson"),
    "repositoryName":  githubv4.String("gha-find-replace"),
    "tagName":         githubv4.String("v3"),
}
err = client.Query(context.Background(), &releaseQ, variables)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Query returned nothing")
}
fmt.Println("author:", releaseQ.Repository.Release.Author)
```

I've successfully got the following two code blocks working for repo description and issue reactions:

```
var repoDescriptionQ struct {
  Repository struct {
    Description string
  } `graphql:"repository(owner: \"jacobtomlinson\", name: \"gha-find-replace\")"`
}
```

this successfully returned repo description ^

```
variables := map[string]interface{}{
  "repositoryOwner": githubv4.String("jacobtomlinson"),
  "repositoryName":  githubv4.String("gha-find-replace"),
  "issueNumber":     githubv4.Int(55),
  "reactionContent": githubv4.ReactionContentThumbsDown,
}
var reactionQ struct {
Repository struct {
    Issue struct {
        ID        githubv4.ID
        Reactions struct {
            ViewerHasReacted githubv4.Boolean
        } `graphql:"reactions(content:$reactionContent)"`
    } `graphql:"issue(number:$issueNumber)"`
} `graphql:"repository(owner:$repositoryOwner,name:$repositoryName)"`
}
```

this successfully got a reaction ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the Author field is not a string but of type "User". Changed the field requested to Description, which is a string, and it is pulling back the release info. If you do want Author you'll need to define User:

```
var releaseQ struct {
    Repository struct {
        Release struct {
            Description githubv4.String
        } `graphql:"release(tagName:$tagName)"`
    } `graphql:"repository(owner:$repositoryOwner,name:$repositoryName)"`
}
```